# Subscribing to an event provided by a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, event-handling

I have a third party application that I'm interacting with via a WCF service that they're exposing.  When my application is loaded, the WCF service is supposed to hook into the callbacks I've defined and give me data back.  This is straight-forward in VB but I think my issue is syntax in accomplishing this in C#.

Their documentation states the following: `Your user control will need to define an internal event with a signature that matches the event that our service is listening for.`

Here are my declarations for the handler, as provided by this services' documentation:

```
public delegate void MyDel(ref string Param1, ref string Param2);
public event MyDel GetInfo;
```

The documentation then says that I should be able to call this event in the following fashion, and the data I need from the service will be inside of the `output` variable I pass in by reference:

```
string output = "";
string methodName = "SpecificAction"

// this is null and throws an exception
// i've tried wrapping it in an if != null block to no avail
GetInfo(ref methodName, ref output);
Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());
```

In VB the following works without issue:

```
Public Event GetInfo (ByRef EventName As String, ByRef XmlString As String)
Dim Output As String = ""
RaiseEvent GetInfo("SpecificAction", Output)
```

The reason that I think I'm doing something wrong with the C# syntax is, as I said, it seems to work in VB just fine.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

### Update

So I'm calling this method from my controls' public constructor, which is failing.  If I move this exact code inside of a button click handler, for instance, its returning the data that I expect.  I'm guessing my program is initializing and hitting that call before their service has hooked in?  Is there a way to wait for that to happen?

Comment: Your events are named differently...

Comment: Their documentation says that it can actually be whatever name I'd like, as long as it matches the signature they're expecting.  I'll update my post to reflect that.

Comment: What application your control is in? `WinForms`, `WPF` maybe `ASP.NET Web Forms` ?

Comment: My application is actually a Windows Forms Control Library (DLL), which I embed into their application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing that the above code worked when I removed it from my constructor and placed it in a button click handler, I realized that the issue was probably that I was trying to access the data before the service had hooked into it.  By instead placing the code inside of my controls `Load` event, I was able to get back the data I needed.